# redhat sso after deletion of Master-realm client in master Realm, Admin login is blank

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, redhat, redhat-sso

Redhat sso after deletion of Master-realm client in master Realm, rdsso admin login (/auth/admin/master/console/) is blank.

And in the rdsso server log, we can see this Error

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-10971) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Since the redsso background is live, we are not trying to troubleshoot more.

Note: We just deleted 1 master-realm client out of 70 and this has messed up our admin login console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Keycloak, the "*realmname*-realm" in the master realm (including 'master-realm') clients are essential for the operation of the admin console. Deleting them will result in the admin console not being operational, as you have noticed. The fix is restoring the client back to its previous state, probably best done through a database restore.

Comment: Yes, I know if I have deleted all then it makes sense. But in our case, we just deleted 1 client from the master realm and then this happened. 

As a test case, we also tried to reproduce the same on the Test server and the result was the same. Just deleting one client and rest of the master-realm is affected.

Comment: Yes, because you deleted a client that is required to be in the state that it is, *for the admin console to work at all*. Once you delete it, it stops working. There is no good reason to delete this client.

Comment: hmmm. At least a warning should be in place from the UI before detection or any major change.